# Golang version control

Tags: go

When I executed command go run . , it produced the error of :
go: github.com/go-xorm/xorm@v0.7.0 requires
github.com/go-xorm/core@v0.0.0-20180322150003-0177c08cee88: invalid pseudo-version: does not match version-control timestamp (2018-03-22T14:29:44Z)

Here is my go.mod file .

```
module github.com/lonng/nanoserver

go 1.14

replace (
    golang.org/x/crypto => github.com/golang/crypto v0.0.0-20181001203147-e3636079e1a4
    golang.org/x/net => github.com/golang/net v0.0.0-20180926154720-4dfa2610cdf3
    golang.org/x/sys => github.com/golang/sys v0.0.0-20180928133829-e4b3c5e90611
    golang.org/x/text => github.com/golang/text v0.3.0
)

require (
    github.com/chanxuehong/rand v0.0.0-20180830053958-4b3aff17f488 // indirect
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.0
    github.com/go-xorm/core v0.6.0
    github.com/go-xorm/xorm v0.7.0
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.6.2
    github.com/lonng/nano v0.4.1-0.20190704005402-15209d995681
    github.com/lonng/nex v1.4.1
    github.com/pborman/uuid v1.2.0
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.0
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.1.0
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.2.1
    github.com/urfave/cli v1.20.1-0.20190203184040-693af58b4d51
    github.com/xxtea/xxtea-go v0.0.0-20170828040851-35c4b17eecf6
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190510104115-cbcb75029529
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190509222800-a4d6f7feada5
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
    gopkg.in/chanxuehong/wechat.v2 v2.0.0-20180924084534-7e0579cb5377
)
```

I first tested the go version and it's go version go1.14.14 windows/amd64

And I tried to modified the go.mod from [github.com/go-xorm/xorm v0.7.0] to [github.com/go-xorm/xorm v0.7.0-20180322150003-0177c08cee88]. But it does not work as well. Are there anyway to synchronize the version for this module or other way to update the specific module separately or just ignore the timestamp?

Comment: first update your version of go, and try `go mod tidy` to fixup any `go.mod` irregularities (go1.14 has been unsupported for over two years)

Comment: go 1.20 was already released. Also update the package versions, they may be well outdated

Comment: I tried to updated go version. But the error is still there.

Comment: I tried to run go mod tidy. But it seems the message is same as I execute go run .

Comment: It's hard to say what went wrong. Maybe, try to start a green project and add the `xorm` package that seems to be the faulty one. If that doesn't solve your issue, you can update the question by adding the minimum reproducible code to work with. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to setup the project in windows. But it seems the project was originally in Mac. Even the go version is also 1.14.14  , maybe that different OS go version cause the timestamp different. 
https://github.com/Kirk-Wang/nanoserver